# Windows Server R2 backup backup types

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2

In regards to Windows server R2 backup, what actually gets backed up on a system state backup? Would this include things like user accounts?

If I did a system state backup along with all volumes (IE. not bare metal), and then restored it onto another server would this keep the target server IP address or the backed up servers IP?

Or am I totally missing something?

Comment: What does your research suggest?

Comment: Well I can't seem to find a definitive definition of what a "system state" backup actually is. So that's not a good start.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. "System state backup creates a backup file for critical system related components. This backup file can be used to recover the critical system components after a crash." So does that mean the original IP would be applied to the restored machine?

Comment: This would depend on your network configuration. Its dead simply to change the ip address of a server.  What does a system state have to do with the ip address?

Comment: True. I think I'm being over curious because I've got to undertake a server migration that I'm not looking forward to doing. So being forewarned goes some way to being forearmed..... so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SYSTEM STATE. A particular configuration of a system by virtue of the
>   position or state of each switch, circuit breaker, solid-state digital
>   device, or other multistate circuit device; or by virtue of the
>   mechanical configuration of doors, equipment, or machines that make up
>   the system. External states include solid-state logic outside the
>   facility barrier, the position of external switches, and
>   configurations of mechanical devices outside the HEMP barrier.
>   Internal states are determined by the configurations of mechanical
>   devices inside the HEMP barrier or by particular circuit connections
>   realized when such things as switches, circuit breakers, thermostatic
>   control, pressure controls, and door interlocks are in a particular
>   on/off arrangement, and electronic states occurring within the system.

[Source](http://www.empengineering.com/index.php/hemp-definitions)

And this may answer your question more specifically:

> The system state contains a number of items:
>
> ```
> System Registry
> COM + Database
> Certificate Services
> Active Directory
> SysVol
> IIS Metabase
> ```
>
> Some of these items are only included if the specified service is
>   installed (AD, IIS, Certificates).
>
> If you need to restore a server, you will need this state to recover
>   the registry, or your AD Domain, or IIS sites.
>
> You can restore system state to the same server, or another server
>   with identical hardware. Microsoft does not support restoring system
>   state to different hardware (see this article), however it is possible
>   in some occasions, and with some parts of the system state, for
>   example the IIS metabase. In that guess its really a case of try it an
>   see, but its not a reccomended solution.

[Source and more answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/17624/what-is-a-system-state-backup-for)

Comment: This sounds like good news, and exactly what I need. Nice one. Thanks for the pointer.... and the sanity check :)

Comment: You are very welcome